# react18 + react-datepicker@4.8.0(node18) can not display component Datepicker

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-datepicker

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

I just make on example from documentation, but I get an error that above:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';

import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';

const Example = () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());

  return (
    <DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={(date: Date) => setStartDate(date)}
    />
  );
};
```

maybe someone faced a similar problem, I will be grateful for help

Answer (score 0):

there is no issue in the 'react-datepicker' package. I have checked the above code it is working correctly.

I also faced the same issue so when I checked my code I had written one function outside the primary function. So that's why this issue comes you can check your other file code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try to find problem in my code or try to use another library